# Why does iOS swift segue stop working when changing development computer?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, segue

I'm building a multiple view iOS app using Swift and Xcode.

I've defined a segue by control-dragging from a button in one view to the new view.

Everything works on the first Mac. When I check in the code, and try to run it on another computer, the button stops working. It displays a black screen instead inside the simulator.

If I redo the control-drag on the second machine, then it works there, but breaks on the first.

I can see that Main.storyboard changes between the two systems. Specifically, the it's the ID in:

< segue destination="xx-yy-zzz" kind="show" id="1234" />

What is the right way to make this segue work?

Answer (score -1):

Not 100% sure why this happens but if you are working with multiple developers, I find that having the same Xcode versions is Key. If you are indeed certain that you checked in changes and that you have pulled those changes on the other machine, check your Xcode versions.

I find this article a good resource regarding version control and storyboards.

http://mbehan.com/post/77229582565/storyboards-multiple-developers-and-git